# How much ETC was stolen in the multiple 51% attacks on Ethereum-Classic?

Tags: ethereum-classic, attacks, hack

Ethereum Classic was attacked multiple times back in 2020. How much was stolen and which addresses control these stolen funds now? And have they been sold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In January 2019, an attack on Ethereum Classic resulted in the theft of about `219,500 ETC`, worth approximately `$1.1 million` at the time.

In August 2020, an attack led to the theft of about `807,260 ETC`, worth approximately `$5.6 million` at the time.

In January 2021, the last 51% attack on Ethereum Classic resulted in the theft of about `7,000 ETC`, worth around `$9 million` at the time.

It's possible that some of the stolen ETC from the 51% attack on Ethereum Classic was sold on various cryptocurrency exchanges, but it's hard to say exactly if they were sold or not.

Comment: do we know which addresses the attack funneled the funds through?